# Meteor.js porting for Adobe Edge Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, adobe-edge, meteor-blaze

I have just created a template in Adobe Edge animate, and the export gives out the following files:

```
/edge_includes/edge.3.0.0.min.js
/edge_includes/jquery-2.0.3.min.js
/index_edge.js
/index_edgeActions.js
/index_edgePreload.js
/index.html
```

The 'index.html' file loads '/index_edgePreload.js' in the head, which further loads  '/edge_includes/edge.3.0.0.min.js', '/edge_includes/jquery-2.0.3.min.js', '/index_edge.js' and '/index_edgeActions.js'

Here is sample template code: https://github.com/praneybehl/Adobe-Edge-sample-template

Can someone please suggest how to possiblly get this code running in a Meteor Template?

Thanks in advance,
Praney

Comment: You need to provide some more details. What kind of errors are you getting? The repository you provided contains only minified files, so they're not readable.

Comment: @apendua Thanks mate, but that what Adobe Edge animate exports. Maybe I can beautify them and upload